# Isabelle solvers: "auto" or "fastforce"? (comparison of solver strength)

Tags: solver, isabelle, theorem-proving

In Isabelle, I often find that I can prove a goal successfully using different solvers.

Generally I would prefer to use the **weakest solver that can just about prove the goal**. Based on my experience with Isabelle so far, my current understanding is that in order of *increasing strength* and *decreasing speed*, the common logic solvers rank as follows (i.e. when `rule` and `simp` both work, `rule` should be used, etc.):

```
rule < simp < auto < fastforce < force
```

**Is this correct? Where does `blast` fit in here?**

I checked [Programming and Proving in Isabelle/HOL (PDF)](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/hvg/Isabelle/dist/Isabelle2014/doc/prog-prove.pdf) and [Concrete Semantics with Isabelle/HOL](http://www.concrete-semantics.org/) but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There generally is no linear ordering on the strength of proving methods and your word "weakest" assume there is one. We can nevertheless say that "auto" generally have at least the power of "simp" or "rule" but as it is more powerful it can also do some useless work that can make it fail. fastforce, bestsimp and slowsimp have the same power with different proof search strategies.

I can't really say more details on this, but maybe someone else could.

Comment: I posted a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28644151/3507119) about the difference between `arith` and `presburger` since that seems relatively unrelated.

Comment: Can you point me to a description of the proof strategies employed by `fastforce`, `bestsimp`, `slowsimp` etc.?

Comment: The most detailed description I could find was in section 9.4.4 of the Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual (http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2014/doc/isar-ref.pdf). I have never used `bestsimp`, `slow`, `fast` etc. myself; they are very rare. `assumption`, `fact`, `rule`, `erule`, `intro`, `elim`, `clarify`, `simp`, `simp_all`, `blast`, `fastforce`, `force`, `auto` and sometimes more specialised ones like `induction`, `arith`, `algebra`, etc. are the methods I use normally. Most of the time, you can get by with `auto` and `simp`/`simp_all`.